# How do I fine-tune regex syntax to parse a tricky dirty text?

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I have an OCR'ed .txt file that is a volume with data about book reviews (It's a Book Review Index). I'm attempting to separate authors, titles, and review data. I've been able to cleanly separate authors, but still can't separate titles from review data cleanly. Here is a sample of the .txt file:

> MA, Chi-Hua - Huan Chiu Hsin Ying BL - v70 - Jl 1 ’74 - pi 183 c MA, Ching-Hsien - Pei Niang Niang Ti Ku Shih
>   BL - v77 - Ja 1 ’81 - p630 MA, Hsin-Teh - Chinese Women In The Great Leap Forward
>   Choice - v20 - N ’82 - p396 MA, Huan • The Overall Survey Of The Ocean’s Shores 1433
>   Choice - v8 - 0 ’71 - pl074 MA, Huan • Ying-Yai Sheng-Lan AHR - v76 - D ’71 - pl578 GJ - vl37 - Je ’71 - p213 JAS - v31 - N ’71 - pl81 TLS - Je 16 ’72 - p681 MA, Laurence J C - Commercial Development And Urban Change In Sung China 960-1279
>   JAS - v31 - Ag ’72 - p928 Pac A - v45 - Summer ’72 - p285 MA, Laurence J C - The Environment JAS - v42 - N ’82 - pl39 MA, Laurence J C - Urban Development In Modern China
>   Choice - vl9 - Ja ’82 - p696 JAS - v42 - N 82 - pl39 MA, Nancy Chih - Cook Chinese AB - v45 - My 25 ’70 - pl786 PW - vl97 - Mr 23 ’70 - p38 MA, Nancy Chih • Don’t Lick The Chopsticks CSM - v66 - Ja 10 ’74 - pF2 LJ - v99 - Mr 15 ’74 - p757 MA, Nancy Chih - Mrs. Ma’s Japanese Cooking
>   VQR - v58 - Spring ’82 - p68 MA, Tsu Sheng - Microscale Manipulations In Chemistry
>   Choice-vl3-N ’76 -pi 164 MA, Tsu Sheng - Organic Functional Group Analysis By Gas Chromatography Choice - vl3 - F ’77 - pl624 r MA, Wei-Yi - A Bibliography Of Chinese-Language Materials On The People's Communes ARBA - vl5 - '84 - p320
>   Pac A - v56 - Winter ’83 - p796 MA, Wook - Seoul Ro Kanun Kil BL - v78 - 0 15 '81 - p294 y MA, Y W - Traditional Chinese Stories ANQ - vl8 - 0 ’79 - p30 BF - v4 - Ap 40 '79 - p575 Choice -vl5-Ja ’79 -pl528 HR-v32-Spring'79-pl23 JAS - v38 - Ag '79 - p773 Kliatt - vl3 • Winter '79 - p26 WIT - v53 - Summer '79 - p555 MA, Yun • Shih Ching T'ao Hsing BL - v68 - Ap 1 '72 - p651 MA BRICALL, Josep - Politica Economica De La Generalitat 1936-1939. Vol. 1 WP - v25 - O '72 - pl55 MA COY, Ramelle • Short-Time Compensation
>   Choice - v21 - Jl '84 - pl648 Econ Bks - vll - S ’84 - p62 c MA De - The Cowherd And The Weaving Maid
>   Cur R - v20 - S '81 -p325 c MA De - Crickets
>   Cur R - v20 - S '81 - p325 c MA De - School-Master Dongguo Cur R - v20 - S '81 - p325 c MA De - Thrice Borrowing The Plantain Fan CurR- v20-S ’81 -p325 c MA De - The Wonderful Gourds Cur R - v20 - S '81 - p325 MAACK, Berthold - Preussen JMH - v55 - Mr '83 - p71 r MAACK, Mary N - Libraries In Senegal ARBA - vl3 - '82 - pi53 CRL - v45 - Mr '84-pl52 JAL - v7 - S '81 - p244 JLH - vl9 - Spring ’84 - p315 LJ - vl07 - My 1 ’82 - p865 LQ - v52 - Ap '82-pl75 MAACK, Reinhard • Kontinentaldrift Und Geologie Des Sudatlantischen Ozeans GJ - vl36 - Mr '70 - pl38 MAAG, Russell C - Observe And Understand The Sun
>   S&T - v54 - S ’77 - p221 MAAG, Victor - Hiob
>   Rel St Rev - vlO - Ap '84 - pi 75 MAAILMA Katettu Poyta

And here is a cleaner version, to see better what I'm trying to separate:

> MA, Chi-Hua - Huan Chiu Hsin Ying BL - v70 - Jl 1 ’74 - pi 183 c 
>   MA, Ching-Hsien - Pei Niang Niang Ti Ku Shih BL - v77 - Ja 1 ’81 - p630 
>   MA, Hsin-Teh - Chinese Women In The Great Leap Forward Choice - v20 - N ’82 - p396 
>   MA, Huan • The Overall Survey Of The Ocean’s Shores 1433 Choice - v8 - 0 ’71 - pl074 
>   MA, Huan • Ying-Yai Sheng-Lan AHR - v76 - D ’71 - pl578 GJ - vl37 - Je ’71 - p213 JAS - v31 - N ’71 - pl81 TLS - Je 16 ’72 - p681 
>   MA, Laurence J C - Commercial Development And Urban Change In Sung China 960-1279 JAS - v31 - Ag ’72 - p928 Pac A - v45 - Summer ’72 - p285 
>   MA, Laurence J C - The Environment JAS - v42 - N ’82 - pl39 
>   MA, Laurence J C - Urban Development In Modern China Choice - vl9 - Ja ’82 - p696 JAS - v42 - N 82 - pl39 
>   MA, Nancy Chih - Cook Chinese AB - v45 - My 25 ’70 - pl786 PW - vl97 - Mr 23 ’70 - p38 
>   MA, Nancy Chih • Don’t Lick The Chopsticks CSM - v66 - Ja 10 ’74 - pF2 LJ - v99 - Mr 15 ’74 - p757 
>   MA, Nancy Chih - Mrs. Ma’s Japanese Cooking VQR - v58 - Spring ’82 - p68 
>   MA, Tsu Sheng - Microscale Manipulations In Chemistry Choice-vl3-N ’76 -pi 164 
>   MA, Tsu Sheng - Organic Functional Group Analysis By Gas Chromatography Choice - vl3 - F ’77 - pl624 r 
>   MA, Wei-Yi - A Bibliography Of Chinese-Language Materials On The People's Communes ARBA - vl5 - '84 - p320 Pac A - v56 - Winter ’83 - p796 
>   MA, Wook - Seoul Ro Kanun Kil BL - v78 - 0 15 '81 - p294 y 
>   MA, Y W - Traditional Chinese Stories ANQ - vl8 - 0 ’79 - p30 BF - v4 - Ap 40 '79 - p575 Choice -vl5-Ja ’79 -pl528 HR-v32-Spring'79-pl23 JAS - v38 - Ag '79 - p773 Kliatt - vl3 • Winter '79 - p26 WIT - v53 -  Summer '79 - p555 
>   MA, Yun • Shih Ching T'ao Hsing BL - v68 - Ap 1 '72 - p651 
>   MA BRICALL, Josep - Politica Economica De La Generalitat 1936-1939. Vol. 1 WP - v25 - O '72 - pl55 
>   MA COY, Ramelle • Short-Time Compensation Choice - v21 - Jl '84 - pl648 Econ Bks - vll - S ’84 - p62 c 
>   MA De - The Cowherd And The Weaving Maid Cur R - v20 - S '81 -p325 c 
>   MA De - Crickets Cur R - v20 - S '81 - p325 c 
>   MA De - School-Master Dongguo Cur R - v20 - S '81 - p325 c 
>   MA De - Thrice Borrowing The Plantain Fan CurR- v20-S ’81 -p325 c 
>   MA De - The Wonderful Gourds Cur R - v20 - S '81 - p325 
>   MAACK, Berthold - Preussen JMH - v55 - Mr '83 - p71 r

And here's my code:

```
# read in review volume .txt file
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

file = '/Users/sinykin/Dropbox/US_LIT_PRODUCTION_DATA/REVIEWS_DATA/BOOK_REVIEWS_INDEX_TEXTS/1965_1984_Vol_5_M-P.txt'

with open(file) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    content = [x.strip() for x in content]
    content = " ".join(content)

# Get all authors
pattern = r"[A-Z\-]{2,}[\,]+\s[A-Za-z\s\,\(\)\.]+\s[\-\*\•\.\■ ]{1}"
authors = re.findall(pattern, content)

# Now replace all found authors with XXX_XXX
if re.search(pattern, content):
    r = re.compile(pattern)
    content2 = r.sub(r'XXX_XXX', content)

# Now get all the content for each author
content3 = content2.split('XXX_XXX')
bib = content3[1:]

# Now separate reviews from titles
pattern2 = r"\s+(?:([A-Z][a-z][a-z]((?!\s+-|\s+Choice\s*-).)*?\w)(?:\s+-
\s*|\s+(?=Choice\s*-)|\s*$))"
bib2 = "".join(bib)
titles = re.findall(pattern2, bib2)
print (titles[:1000])
```

It's the regex code in pattern2 that I'm struggling with. For example, it currently gives me this, for what should be titles:

> [('The Overall Survey Of The Ocean\xe2\x80\x99s Shores 1433', '3'),
>   ('Ying-Yai Sheng-Lan AHR', 'H'),
>   ('Commercial Development And Urban Change In Sung China 960-1279 JAS', 'A'),
>   ('Pac A', ' '),
>   ('Summer \xe2\x80\x9972', '7'),
>   ('The Environment JAS', 'A'),
>   ('Urban Development In Modern China', 'n'),
>   ('Cook Chinese AB', 'A'),
>   ('Don\xe2\x80\x99t Lick The Chopsticks CSM', 'S'),
>   ('Mrs. Ma\xe2\x80\x99s Japanese Cooking VQR', 'Q'), 
>   ('Spring \xe2\x80\x9982', '8'),
>   ('Microscale Manipulations In Chemistry', 'r')

As you can see, I'm getting extra data beyond the end of the titles, esp capital letters that mark abbreviation for reviews.

Can you help me refine my regex to capture just the titles?

Answer (score 0):

You could keep building up on the last positive lookahead, by adding some specific expressions, to screen out the unwanted trailing characters. For example, extending

`(?:\s+-\s*|\s+(?=Choice\s*-)|\s*$))`

into

`(?:\s+-\s*|\s+(?=Choice\s*-)|\s*$|\s+[A-Z]{2,3}|\s+Cur R))`

would eliminate the `Cur R` and code endings (`AB`, `JAS`, etc.):

> ('The Environment', 'n')
>   ('Urban Development In Modern China', 'n')
>   ('Cook Chinese', 's')
>   ('Nancy Chih \xe2\x80\xa2 Don\xe2\x80\x99t Lick The Chopsticks', 'k')
>   ('Mrs. Ma\xe2\x80\x99s Japanese Cooking', 'n')

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: ... refine my regex to capture just the titles?

Split `content2` on these Patterns to get a List of Books:

```
books = []
for c in re.split('(XXX_XXX|MA, | MA, | MA )', content2):
    if c and not c in ['MA, ', ' MA, ', ' MA ', 'XXX_XXX']:
        books.append(c.strip())
```

Loop `books` to extract the `title`:

```
reObj = re.compile(r'(.+?)(( [A-Z\&]{1,4})?| Choice| Cur ?R) ?- ?[’v][l]?(\d{1,2}|O )')
for book in books:
    match = reObj.match(book)
    if match:
        title = match.groups()[0]
        print('{}'.format(title))
    else:
        print('FAIL:{}'.format(book))
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> Chi-Hua - Huan Chiu Hsin Ying
> Ching-Hsien - Pei Niang Niang Ti Ku Shih
> Hsin-Teh - Chinese Women In The Great Leap Forward
> The Overall Survey Of The Ocean’s Shores 1433
> Ying-Yai Sheng-Lan
> Commercial Development And Urban Change In Sung China 960-1279
> The Environment
> Urban Development In Modern China
> Cook Chinese
> Don’t Lick The Chopsticks
> ... (omitted for brevity)
> ```

***Tested with Python:3.4.2 - re:2.2.1***